# C# Отправка xml через POST

Tags: c#, post

Добрый день! Пытаюсь отправить методом POST xml-файл (в УТМ ЕГАИС). В ответ сервер выдает ошибку Error 500 Server Error HTTP ERROR 500 Problem accessing /opt/in/QueryRests_v2. Reason:Server Error Caused by:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Incomplete parts. Где что не до заполнил, подскажите, пожалуйста. 
Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest oRequest = null;
        oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://169.254.0.165:8080/opt/in/QueryRests_v2");
        oRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=\"AaB03x\"";
        oRequest.Method = "POST";
        //PostData pData = new PostData();

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GetPostData());

        // Set content length of our data
        oRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        // Dump our buffered postdata to the stream, booyah
        Stream oStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream();
        oStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        oStream.Close();

        try
        {
            // get the response
            HttpWebResponse oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse();
        }catch(WebException webex)
        {
            string exMessage = webex.Message;

            if (webex.Response != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    exMessage = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetPostData()
    {
        // Get boundary, default is --AaB03x
        string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 8\"?><ns:Documents Version=\"1.0\"xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xmlns:ns=\"http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/WB_DOC_SINGLE_01\"xmlns:qp=\"http://fsrar.ru/WEGAIS/QueryParameters\"><ns:Owner><ns:FSRAR_ID>000000000000</ns:FSRAR_ID></ns:Owner><ns:Document><ns:QueryRests_v2></ns:QueryRests_v2></ns:Document></ns:Documents>";
        string boundary = "--AaB03x";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(boundary);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"", "xml_file", "select.xml"));
        sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        //sb.AppendLine("multipart/form-data");
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine(xml);
        sb.AppendLine(boundary);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

П.С. Может есть у кого пример кода по отправке запросов в УТМ ЕГАИС через POST?

Comment: Сохрание переменную `xml` в файл. Если это АПИ, то как правило АПИ не использует multipart/form-data. Вот не помню нужен ли разделитель для одного параметра, вероятнее всего - нет, и возможно именно '--AaB03x' и приводит к сбою.

Comment: Попробуйте закоментить  `sb.AppendLine(boundary);`

Comment: Если указать Content-Type отличный от multipart/form-data,  сервер возвращает ошибку Content-Type != multipart/form-data. Если закоментить sb.AppendLine(boundary) - сервер вернет Missing initial multi part boundary

Comment: https://infostart.ru/public/398079/ - пример отправки запроса в 1С в УТМ. Но я не могу сообразить, как его перевести на c#, поскольку плохо владею 1Сом

Comment: Ваш xml невалидный. Почему, собственно, вы не пользуетесь специализированными средствами для формирования xml, а склеиваете его вручную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Андрей NOP. Файл действительно был не валидный. Сформировал его средствами и все ушло. Так же не хватало \r\n после последнего boundary